# Scrapy only finding some files at beginning of crawl

Tags: android, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy, apk

I'm using a command-line application from github (https://github.com/mssun/android-apps-crawler, runnning on a linux virtualbox) to scrape a third party appstore (www.mumayi.com) for all the apk files they host, so that i can analyse them. I know that the site has rather a lot of APKs.

However, when i run the program, at first it works really well and finds files rather quickly (35-50 on average), then inserting them into a database for download at a later time, but after 1-2 minutes of working well it can't find any more, no matter how long i leave it running, even though i know that there are a lot more APK files on there.

Is there anyone that could suggest why this happens? Is it something to do with the site not liking that i'm looking through their files with a program?

I've included a sample log from the command line below, note that i only let this one run for about 10 mins after it stopped finding files, I've let other ones run for 24 hours, and still the same result.

```
matt@matt-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/android-apps-crawler-master/crawler$ ./crawl.sh mumayi.com
/home/matt/Downloads/android-apps-crawler-master/crawler/android_apps_crawler/spiders/android_apps_spider.py:3: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
from scrapy.spider import Spider
/home/matt/Downloads/android-apps-crawler-master/crawler/android_apps_crawler/spiders/android_apps_spider.py:7: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.log` has been deprecated, Scrapy now relies on the builtin Python library for logging. Read the updated logging entry in the documentation to learn more.
from scrapy import log
2015-08-31 09:38:28 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: android_apps_crawler)
2015-08-31 09:38:28 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-08-31 09:38:28 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'android_apps_crawler.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['android_apps_crawler.spiders'], 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11', 'BOT_NAME': 'android_apps_crawler'}
2015-08-31 09:38:28 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-08-31 09:38:28 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: DownloaderMiddleware, HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-08-31 09:38:28 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
../repo/databases/mumayi.com.db
2015-08-31 09:38:28 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: AppPipeline, SQLitePipeline
2015-08-31 09:38:28 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-08-31 09:38:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:38:41 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/matt/Downloads/android-apps-crawler-master/crawler/android_apps_crawler/spiders/android_apps_spider.py:85: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: log.msg has been deprecated, create a python logger and log through it instead
log.msg("Catch an application: %s" % url, level=log.INFO)

2015-08-31 09:38:41 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/54049
2015-08-31 09:38:41 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/matt/Downloads/android-apps-crawler-master/crawler/android_apps_crawler/pipelines.py:12: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: log.msg has been deprecated, create a python logger and log through it instead
log.msg("Catch an AppItem", level=log.INFO)

2015-08-31 09:38:41 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:41 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/matt/Downloads/android-apps-crawler-master/crawler/android_apps_crawler/pipelines.py:33: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: log.msg has been deprecated, create a python logger and log through it instead
log.msg("Inserting into database");

2015-08-31 09:38:41 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:44 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/989871
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/1003630
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/217624
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/970142
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:45 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
Ignore request!
Ignore request!
Ignore request!
2015-08-31 09:38:47 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/42860
2015-08-31 09:38:47 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/555845
2015-08-31 09:38:47 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:47 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:47 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:47 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:47 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/121890
2015-08-31 09:38:47 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:47 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:48 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/197417
2015-08-31 09:38:48 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:48 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:48 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/254262
2015-08-31 09:38:48 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:48 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:49 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/308575
2015-08-31 09:38:49 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:49 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/227335
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://down.mumayi.com/minisetup/970142> (referer: http://www.mumayi.com/android-970142.html)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
yield next(it)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 28, in process_spider_output
for x in result:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "/home/matt/Downloads/android-apps-crawler-master/crawler/android_apps_crawler/spiders/android_apps_spider.py", line 36, in parse
self.parse_xpath(response, xpath_rule[key]))
File "/home/matt/Downloads/android-apps-crawler-master/crawler/android_apps_crawler/spiders/android_apps_spider.py", line 82, in parse_xpath
sel = Selector(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 80, in __init__
_root = LxmlDocument(response, self._parser)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmldocument.py", line 27, in __new__
cache[parser] = _factory(response, parser)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmldocument.py", line 13, in _factory
body = response.body_as_unicode().strip().encode('utf8') or '<html/>'
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode'
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/45243
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/7937
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/858308
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:50 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:51 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:51 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/499346
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/1003438
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/549777
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/1002249
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:52 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:38:53 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/335562
2015-08-31 09:38:53 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:38:53 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:21 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/51129
2015-08-31 09:39:21 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:21 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:22 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/72090
2015-08-31 09:39:22 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:22 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:23 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/318245
2015-08-31 09:39:23 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:23 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:23 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/52958
2015-08-31 09:39:23 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:24 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:25 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/212803
2015-08-31 09:39:25 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:25 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/287
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/426381
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/32326
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/113156
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:26 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 184 pages (at 184 pages/min), scraped 29 items (at 29 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/230146
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/208
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://down.mumayi.com/minisetup/318245> (referer: http://www.mumayi.com/android-318245.html)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
yield next(it)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 28, in process_spider_output
for x in result:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "/home/matt/Downloads/android-apps-crawler-master/crawler/android_apps_crawler/spiders/android_apps_spider.py", line 36, in parse
self.parse_xpath(response, xpath_rule[key]))
File "/home/matt/Downloads/android-apps-crawler-master/crawler/android_apps_crawler/spiders/android_apps_spider.py", line 82, in parse_xpath
sel = Selector(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 80, in __init__
_root = LxmlDocument(response, self._parser)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmldocument.py", line 27, in __new__
cache[parser] = _factory(response, parser)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmldocument.py", line 13, in _factory
body = response.body_as_unicode().strip().encode('utf8') or '<html/>'
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode'
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/59
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:30 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/882209
2015-08-31 09:39:30 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:30 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:30 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/987896
2015-08-31 09:39:30 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/97686
2015-08-31 09:39:30 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:30 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:30 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:30 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/979277
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/350618
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/343323
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/21799
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/485394
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:31 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:32 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/24615
2015-08-31 09:39:32 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:32 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:32 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/872176
2015-08-31 09:39:32 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:32 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:32 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/63575
2015-08-31 09:39:32 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:32 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:33 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/1007326
2015-08-31 09:39:33 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:33 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:35 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/62258
2015-08-31 09:39:35 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:35 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:35 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/64880
2015-08-31 09:39:35 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:35 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:35 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/455675
2015-08-31 09:39:35 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:35 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:36 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/851783
2015-08-31 09:39:36 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:36 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:40 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/14037
2015-08-31 09:39:40 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:40 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:39:43 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an application: http://down.mumayi.com/274799
2015-08-31 09:39:43 [scrapy] INFO: Catch an AppItem
2015-08-31 09:39:43 [scrapy] INFO: Inserting into database
2015-08-31 09:40:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 333 pages (at 149 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 21 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:41:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 538 pages (at 205 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:42:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 795 pages (at 257 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:43:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 1044 pages (at 249 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:44:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 1269 pages (at 225 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:45:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 1616 pages (at 347 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:46:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 2041 pages (at 425 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:47:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 2417 pages (at 376 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:48:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 2790 pages (at 373 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:49:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 3131 pages (at 341 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-31 09:50:28 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 3463 pages (at 332 pages/min), scraped 50 items (at 0 items/min)
^C2015-08-31 09:51:11 [scrapy] INFO: Received SIGINT, shutting down gracefully. Send again to force 
2015-08-31 09:51:11 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (shutdown)
2015-08-31 09:51:21 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 3,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 3,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 5030837,
 'downloader/request_count': 4613,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4613,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 49981622,
 'downloader/response_count': 4613,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3742,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 871,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 545833,
 'finish_reason': 'shutdown',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31, 8, 51, 21, 908163),
 'item_scraped_count': 50,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 170,
 'log_count/WARNING': 3,
 'offsite/domains': 140,
 'offsite/filtered': 81248,
 'request_depth_max': 143,
 'response_received_count': 3742,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4616,
 'scheduler/dequeued/disk': 4616,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 20763,
 'scheduler/enqueued/disk': 20763,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31, 8, 38, 28, 184357)}
2015-08-31 09:51:21 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (shutdown)
```

Code of my spider:

```
import re

from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy import log

from urlparse import urlparse
from urlparse import urljoin

from android_apps_crawler.items import AppItem
from android_apps_crawler import settings
from android_apps_crawler import custom_parser


class AndroidAppsSpider(Spider):
    name = "android_apps_spider"
    scrape_rules = settings.SCRAPE_RULES

    def __init__(self, market=None, database_dir="../repo/databases/", *args, **kwargs):
        super(AndroidAppsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.allowed_domains = settings.ALLOWED_DOMAINS[market]
        self.start_urls = settings.START_URLS[market]
        settings.MARKET_NAME = market
        settings.DATABASE_DIR = database_dir

    def parse(self, response):
        response_domain = urlparse(response.url).netloc
        appItemList = []
        cookie = {}
        xpath_rule = self.scrape_rules['xpath']
        for key in xpath_rule.keys():
            if key in response_domain:
                appItemList.extend(
                        self.parse_xpath(response, xpath_rule[key]))
                break
        custom_parser_rule = self.scrape_rules['custom_parser']
        for key in custom_parser_rule.keys():
            if key in response_domain:
                appItemList.extend(
                        getattr(custom_parser, custom_parser_rule[key])(response))
                break
        #if "appchina" in response_domain:
        #    xpath = "//a[@id='pc-download' and @class='free']/@href"
        #    appItemList.extend(self.parse_xpath(response, xpath))
        #elif "hiapk" in response_domain:
        #    xpath = "//a[@class='linkbtn d1']/@href"
        #    appItemList.extend(self.parse_xpath(response, xpath))
        #elif "android.d.cn" in response_domain:
        #    xpath = "//a[@class='down']/@href"
        #    appItemList.extend(self.parse_xpath(response, xpath))
        #elif "anzhi" in response_domain:
        #    xpath = "//div[@id='btn']/a/@onclick"
        #    appItemList.extend(self.parse_anzhi(response, xpath))
        #else:
        #    pass
        sel = Selector(response)
        for url in sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
            url = urljoin(response.url, url)
            yield Request(url, meta=cookie, callback=self.parse)

        for item in appItemList:
            yield item


    #def parse_appchina(self, response):
    #    appItemList = []
    #    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    #    for url in hxs.select(
    #        "//a[@id='pc-download' and @class='free']/@href"
    #        ).extract():
    #        url = urljoin(response.url, url)
    #        log.msg("Catch an application: %s" % url, level=log.INFO)
    #        appItem = AppItem()
    #        appItem['url'] = url
    #        appItemList.append(appItem)
    #    return appItemList

    def parse_xpath(self, response, xpath):
        appItemList = []
        sel = Selector(response)
        for url in sel.xpath(xpath).extract():
            url = urljoin(response.url, url)
            log.msg("Catch an application: %s" % url, level=log.INFO)
            appItem = AppItem()
           appItem['url'] = url
            appItemList.append(appItem)
        return appItemList

    #def parse_anzhi(self, response, xpath):
    #    appItemList = []
    #    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    #    for script in hxs.select(xpath).extract():
    #        id = re.search(r"\d+", script).group()
    #        url = "http://www.anzhi.com/dl_app.php?s=%s&n=5" % (id,)
    #        appItem = AppItem()
    #        appItem['url'] = url
    #        appItemList.append(appItem)
    #    return appItemList
```

Comment: Please add the code of your spider to the question. Without knowing the code I can only make a wild guess: The dupefilter/filtered count is rather high. Maybe you need to add a 'dont_filter' to your requests!?

Comment: Added the code from my spider, i'll try turning off filtering now if i can find where the code for it is!

Comment: okay, added don't_filter=True to the request, It seems to be finding alot more apps! unfortunately, it's now popping up with this error a once every couple of seconds

Comment: 2015-08-31 11:42:41 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET tencent://Message/?Uin=800001832&websiteName=q-zone.qq.com&Menu=yes>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 40, in download_request
    raise NotSupported("Unsupported URL scheme '%s': %s" % (scheme, msg))
NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme 'tencent': no handler available for that scheme

Comment: The code seems to get `URLs` that do not start with `http` but `tencent` which is obviously not a valid `URL scheme`. Maybe you should ask the author of `android-app-crawler` what's going on.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for the help. I've emailed the author, so hopefully should have some kind of idea how to fix it soon, would you like to post an answer with the don't_filter suggestion so i can vote it as a good answer, it helped alot.